# Embed Google Maps Window ind DWC

Tags: google-maps, embed, bbj

How can i embed a Google Maps Window in DWC Application.

When i try it with BBjHtmlView.setURL() Google tells me it is not allowed to embed maps in here.

```
htmlFrame! = window!.addHtmlView(window!.getAvailableControlID(),0,0,0,0,"")
htmlFrame!.setUrl("https://www.google.com/maps/place/Basis+Europe+Distribution+GmbH/@49.2404304,6.953361,17z/data=!3m2!4b1!5s0x4795b161069d159f:0x738a8eb4d9c991db!4m6!3m5!1s0x4795b16101a09af7:0x37c310d943dbdaa6!8m2!3d49.2404269!4d6.9559359!16s%2Fg%2F1tfkdj8s?entry=ttu")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the setText()-Method and get the embed-text from Google Maps in an Iframe

```
text! = "<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2604.897796289821!2d6.9559359!3d49.240426899999996!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4795b16101a09af7%3A0x37c310d943dbdaa6!2sBasis%20Europe%20Distribution%20GmbH!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sde!4v1697793016935!5m2!1sen!2sde" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>"
htmlFrame!.setText(text!)
```